# Array from $_POST variables

Tags: php, arrays, email, paypal

I am trying to send a thank you mail after successful paypal payment transaction from my site.

I am getting product_name from paypal here,

```
echo $_POST['item_name1']; // it displays 1st product's name 

echo $_POST['item_name2']; // it displays 2nd product's name
```

Now i am trying to put all products name into an array and then want to print in mail body.

```
        $N=3; // No of purchased items  
        $itemArray = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {

                 $itemArray[]=$_POST['item_name'.$i];

        }

        $itemList = implode('#', $itemArray);
```

Now in mail message i am trying like this ,

```
        $message = "Dear  ". $_POST['first_name'] ." ,<br/>

We have received payment towards purchase of ". str_replace('#', '<br/>', $itemList)." .<br/>

Thank you for ordering.<br/> ";
```

I am not getting item name in mail body.
Can anyone Help ?

Comment: Have you getting `$itemList` above message ? Can you debug that ?

Comment: what r u getting in mail show the string?

Comment: What I am getting in mail : Dear Nirali,
We have received payment towards purchase of .
Thank you for ordering.

Comment: Debug $itemList as Rikesh suggested. Make sure $itemList contains the items

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is getting the product names from `$_POST['item_name0'];` and `$_POST['item_name1'];`.

Change it to:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$N; $i++ ) {
    $itemArray[]=$_POST['item_name'.$i];
}
```

This should then add the values of `$_POST['item_name1'];` and onwards to your array.

Also, why not just use `implode("</br>", $itemArray);` and cut out the str_replace function?

Comment: item name variables should start from item_name1 and onwards..i changed loop. but still not getting in mail.

Comment: What do you get when you add `echo $itemList;` just after the line where you implode the array?

Comment: I can not debug like that.because this is Notify url which receives IPN.and can not print anything on screen.

Comment: Ok, to debug change your script to this: `mail('youremail@example.com', 'Debug', print_r($_POST, true));`. This will email you the contents of the POST variable so you can check that the product names are actually stored in the variables.

Comment: i got post variables in mail but item_name1 displays with too much leading space,and item_name is truncated

Comment: Can you post the output here?